# CWAC : pass data to WakefulIntentService between alarms when used with AlarmManager

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

When using WakefulIntentService without alarm, one can call

```
WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork(context, intentOfWork);
```

to pass data to the service through the intent.

When used with AlarmManager one can call

```
AlarmListener.scheduleAlarms(AlarmManager mgr, PendingIntent pi, Context ctxt);
```

to pass data through a PendingIntent.

However, this intent is set at the beginning and will always be the same each time the alarm will goes off. What if we need to update the intent data between 2 alarms ?
We could stop the schedule, update the intent and start the alarm again, but is it the correct way ?

Answer (score 1):

> What if we need to update the intent data between 2 alarms ?

Then use the first approach, using `sendWakefulWork()`. The `scheduleAlarms()` approach is for simple scenarios.